# What is the 'it' function in the test script in Create React App template?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

In the test script in the app template created by Create React App, I see a function it() like below:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

Which library does it come from? And what does it do?

Thank you.

Comment: In React, To create tests, you can add it() or test() [ both are from Jest framework] blocks with the name of the test and its code.
Please find the below supportive links.
1. https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests
2. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers

Comment: It seems strange that aside from Facebook Github page, I cannot find anywhere else referring to this function it(). Is it a shorthand for test()? Why isn't it mentioned in Jest docs?

Comment: I had a similar confusion between the purpose of `test` and `it` . They seem to be doing the same thing. I can interchange and everything continues to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create React App uses [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) as its test framework. 
The it function takes a string as a descriptor which lets the user name their tests and find them easily in the case of failure. The arrow function is the actual test code.
Example:

```
function add(x,y){
    return x+y;
}

it("adds two and two", ()=> {
    expect(add(2,2)).toEqual(4);
}
```